# Is the range of a vector field $\bigcup_{p\in\mathbb{R}^n}\mathbb{R}_p^n$? ("Calculus on Manifolds" by Michael Spivak.)

Tags: vector-fields, tangent-spaces

I am reading "Calculus on Manifolds" by Michael Spivak.

The author defined a vector field as follows:

> To be precise, a vector field is a function $F$ such that $F(p)\in\mathbb{R}_p^n$ for each $p\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

What is the range of a vector field?

Is the range of a vector field $\bigcup_{p\in\mathbb{R}^n}\mathbb{R}_p^n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whatever reason, we do not really use the word "range" in math after calculus or so in English-speaking countries, preferring "co-domain" or "target" to mean the thing the math hypothetically lands in and "image" to mean the stuff that gets hit by the map.

Assuming you mean co-domain, then yes, your interpretation of Spivak's setup is right, although it would be more precise to write $\bigsqcup_X \mathbb{R}_p^n$ to emphasize that this is a disjoint union. Note also that the union should be "over" $X$ or whatever the vector field is "on," not $\mathbb{R}^n$. Note that this is much much bigger than the image, since a point $p$ must map to an element of $\mathbb{R}_p^n$ (same $p$, not some other $q$).

Comment: hunter, thank you very much for your answer.